# Cannot get data from Basic API to Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, basic-authentication, rest

I have a Basic API connection from Recurly. I want to use that API to get data about my Data Base using Azure Data Factory. I created ls_RestAPI, created ds_RestAPI and created 1 pippeline to proceed to get the data. But there are some problems. My API has Basic Auth as username and no password (Postman Image), header is Accept and Authorization.

[image]

When I start connecting it using ADF, it throws an error due to incorrect syntax. I have provided pictures for you to understand easily.

[image]

[image]

I tried to remove or edit Accept and Authorization but it still doesn't work:

[image]

How can I reconfigure it properly to be able to get data from the above API?

My aim is that after running, Rest API can call all Next Page of API in 1 run. So I use:

```
"paginationRules": {
"AbsoluteUrl": "$.next"
```

but now I have the problem that I can't connect to the API.

Answer (score 0):

ADF Rest connector only expects a Json response. This is mentioned as a warning in one of your screenshots.

[image: warning]

As a result, this is overriding what you have entered for Accept Header.

Could you try firing this API call from some other service like Logic apps?